# What's it for pkgconfig or pc file with Mono?

Tags: mono, pkg-config

After installing Mono, I need to setup environment variable as follows.

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/
```

What's the purpose of pkgconfig files (or .pc files) that are installed in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.8/lib/pkgconfig
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main kind of uses:

- providing compiler and linking flags for compiling the mono runtime inside your own application (embedding): mono-2.pc is an example. These are generally used as follows:

  gcc myprogram.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2`
- providing default lists of managed assemblies for particular subsystems: dotnet.pc provides the assemblies that are normally loaded by default by csc on Windows, gtk-sharp-2.0.pc lists the assemblies of the Gtk+ binding, etc. These are generally used as follows:

  gmcs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 myprogram.cs

If you look inside the files, they have a Description field that should explain what each file is used for.